# Can Bitcoin Core Blockchain initial sync time in BitcoinQT be sped up?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization, bitcoin-qt-setup

Given the following platform hardware and internet data speed (provided below), what settings are recommended for fastest possible blockchain download and sync?

This is the hardware I'm running:

[image: processor, ram, operating system]

[image: storage]

Note: The storage is completely Bitcoin and Monero blockchain data.

[image: internet data speed]

The Bitcoin Core/BitcoinQT client is dreadfully slow.  I've been syncing for a week now.

[image: BitcoinQT initial sync]

My settings are:

[image: BitcoinQT dbcache settings]

[image: BitcoinQT network settings]

[image: Peers]

[image: Network]

Is there anything I need to do programming-wise or hardware upgrade?

I have tried all the other answers found on the stackexchanges and none have worked.  I restart the client each time I make a change.

Comment: What's your Bitcoin Core version? And are you using an HDD or an SSD? I think you could improve performance a bit more by increasing your db cache to e.g. 8 GB but it probably won't make a huge difference.

Comment: I am using an HDD drive and the version of Bitcoin Core that I am using is v22.0.0.  I have already increased the dbcache to 8000 Mb (8 Gb),  to no avail.  If anything, it's performance has slowed down even more.

Comment: I don't have reputable benchmark data on hand, but there are quite a few sources (including anecdotal evidence from myself) that indicate that using an SSD can significantly speed up initial block download, but most of those mentions I've seen were about external drives. I assume you're using an internal drive?

Comment: Correct, I am using an internal drive.  I complete rebuilt my machine from the motherboard out.  My hardware consists of fast AMD 64-bit processors, Radeon GPU, two 1TB SSD internal SSD drives, and 16GB of RAM.  I switched my OS from Windows to the latest stable Linux Ubuntu (will probably switch to Qubes later).  This resolved the problem.   Bitcoin blockchain downloaded in under 24 hours and SYNCED.  Monero blockchain fully downloaded and synced in a few hours.  Thank you for your guidance!